# DJISDK Crash - CheckComponentUpgradeStateWithServer

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

We're getting this crash in our app running on DJI SDK 4.15.1.

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait + 8
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_cond_wait + 1248
2 libc++.1.dylib std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3 DJISDK dji::upgrade::ModuleManager::CheckComponentUpgradeStateWithServer(unsigned long long, dji::upgrade::UpgradeComponent, unsigned long long, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::function<void (dji::upgrade::UpgradeVersionFetchState, dji::upgrade::ComponentVersionCheckState, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, dji::upgrade::DJIUpgradeErrorCode)>) + 6688
4 DJISDK dji::waypointv2::WorkerManager::~WorkerManager() + 772
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start + 320
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start + 8
```

Is there anything known to cause this?

What causes CheckComponentUpgradeStateWithServer to fire?